# Why does Azure key Vault throw a CredentialUnavailableException?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I am using azure key vault with a deployed .net 6 app on azure. Runs fine on my personal azure but when deployed with the client(who has stricter security) it throws this error to the event log on startup:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 6.0.922.41905
.NET Version: 6.0.9
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
- Visual Studio Token provider cant be accessed at D:\DWASFiles\Sites\<APP SERVICE NAME\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json
- Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot
- Azure CLI not installed
- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.
```

I am setting up azure key vault like so in program.cs:

```
if (String.Equals(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"), "Release"))
{
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
    new Uri("https://<KEY VAULT URI>/"),
    new DefaultAzureCredential()); // Auth can be added here, look at link above
}
else
{
    builder.Configuration
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false, true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
```

I have set up an environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in azure also under Configuration|Application settings.

The fact that it runs perfectly ok on my personal azure and does not run on the client azure is suggesting to me that its a configuration issue. I did not have to do anything special to make it work either, it worked straight away.

I will also add that it works perfectly well when I comment out the environment check in startup.cs and use appsettings instead.

I dont have full access to the production azure environment so I cant add/remove/troubleshoot like I would be able to on my dev environment.

All help appreciated, I'm banging my head off the wall here!

Comment: Please share your `appsettings.json` and `Program.cs` file.

Comment: There's nothing exceptional in either of those files but to add more context to the key vault setup, its surrounded by an if statement. I will edit question above to include that.

Comment: What exactly are the client's security restrictions? It sounds like you need to properly authenticate against their key vault.

Comment: @Simmetric I would say they are extremely locked down if I'm being honest. Authenticate against the key vault sounds like what I might need to do. How is this done? This is my first adventure with key vaults so I definitely need to upskill.

Comment: Assuming they've enabled Azure AD Role based access policy, then they will need to create an App Registration for your app in their Azure AD, then provide you with the application ID and Client Secret. They will also need to grant your app registration access to their key vault. Then you need to provide the application ID and client secret in a ClientCredential param, see https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/authenticating-a-client-application-with-azure-key-vault/#using-clientid-and-secret

Comment: What is the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ` value you have set in `Azure App Settings`?

Comment: @Harshitha Its set correctly to 'Release'

Comment: @Simmetric Thank you, the client secret was not set in application settings. API is starting up correctly now.

Comment: Even You need to provide `Access Policy` rights for the Keyvault .

Comment: It is working for me as well.